# Call one function from other an vice versa, complaining about used before defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

In certain conditions I need to call A from B and B from A, but Linter is complaining about 'Used before defined', here is ts code:

```
function _A () {
    if (x) {
        B(); // used befre defined
    }
    ...
}
function B () {
    if (y) {
        _A();
    }
    ...
}
```

If I define B first then it complains in A.
Also note _A is a private method and B will be exported from this file.

Comment: Your snippet [works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/G4QwTgBAHhC8EBcwFcCmBuAUKSBPOiKGmmAZsgHYDGCAlgPYUQD6AggBQCUEA3phAIi1SEdlG59BUiACEu6CAHpFEZAGdUAEwgAjVKTCoIm-bQpb+ggL79MN8tTqNZoiZYHDRuN9MFt57hA2VkA) just fine... please add more information and context and maybe a reproducible example.

Comment: its linting error

Comment: What linter are you using then?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define

Answer (score 3):

Your code works just fine because function declarations are hoisted.

As the linter is there to help you follow best practices, but in this case what you are doing is perfectly valid and intended, maybe is one of those cases where it's ok to [disable that rule there](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/):

```
if (x) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-use-before-define
    B();
}
```

You could also consider completely disabling [that rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-use-before-define.md) if you think it's not helpful for your project or configuring it differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to disable that rule, this will work:

```
let A, B;

A = () => {
  B();
}

B = () => {
  A();
}
```

[playground](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoibGV0IEEsIEI7XG5cbkEgPSAoKSA9PiB7XG4gIEIoKTtcbn1cblxuQiA9ICgpID0+IHtcbiAgQSgpO1xufVxuIiwib3B0aW9ucyI6eyJwYXJzZXJPcHRpb25zIjp7ImVjbWFWZXJzaW9uIjoxMSwic291cmNlVHlwZSI6InNjcmlwdCIsImVjbWFGZWF0dXJlcyI6e319LCJydWxlcyI6eyJjb25zdHJ1Y3Rvci1zdXBlciI6MiwiZm9yLWRpcmVjdGlvbiI6MiwiZ2V0dGVyLXJldHVybiI6Miwibm8tYXN5bmMtcHJvbWlzZS1leGVjdXRvciI6Miwibm8tY2FzZS1kZWNsYXJhdGlvbnMiOjIsIm5vLWNsYXNzLWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tY29tcGFyZS1uZWctemVybyI6Miwibm8tY29uZC1hc3NpZ24iOjIsIm5vLWNvbnN0LWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tY29uc3RhbnQtY29uZGl0aW9uIjoyLCJuby1jb250cm9sLXJlZ2V4IjoyLCJuby1kZWJ1Z2dlciI6Miwibm8tZGVsZXRlLXZhciI6Miwibm8tZHVwZS1hcmdzIjoyLCJuby1kdXBlLWNsYXNzLW1lbWJlcnMiOjIsIm5vLWR1cGUta2V5cyI6Miwibm8tZHVwbGljYXRlLWNhc2UiOjIsIm5vLWVtcHR5IjoyLCJuby1lbXB0eS1jaGFyYWN0ZXItY2xhc3MiOjIsIm5vLWVtcHR5LXBhdHRlcm4iOjIsIm5vLWV4LWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tZXh0cmEtYm9vbGVhbi1jYXN0IjoyLCJuby1leHRyYS1zZW1pIjoyLCJuby1mYWxsdGhyb3VnaCI6Miwibm8tZnVuYy1hc3NpZ24iOjIsIm5vLWdsb2JhbC1hc3NpZ24iOjIsIm5vLWlubmVyLWRlY2xhcmF0aW9ucyI6Miwibm8taW52YWxpZC1yZWdleHAiOjIsIm5vLWlycmVndWxhci13aGl0ZXNwYWNlIjoyLCJuby1taXNsZWFkaW5nLWNoYXJhY3Rlci1jbGFzcyI6Miwibm8tbWl4ZWQtc3BhY2VzLWFuZC10YWJzIjoyLCJuby1uZXctc3ltYm9sIjoyLCJuby1vYmotY2FsbHMiOjIsIm5vLW9jdGFsIjoyLCJuby1wcm90b3R5cGUtYnVpbHRpbnMiOjIsIm5vLXJlZGVjbGFyZSI6Miwibm8tcmVnZXgtc3BhY2VzIjoyLCJuby1zZWxmLWFzc2lnbiI6Miwibm8tc2hhZG93LXJlc3RyaWN0ZWQtbmFtZXMiOjIsIm5vLXNwYXJzZS1hcnJheXMiOjIsIm5vLXRoaXMtYmVmb3JlLXN1cGVyIjoyLCJuby11bmRlZiI6Miwibm8tdW5leHBlY3RlZC1tdWx0aWxpbmUiOjIsIm5vLXVucmVhY2hhYmxlIjoyLCJuby11bnNhZmUtZmluYWxseSI6Miwibm8tdW5zYWZlLW5lZ2F0aW9uIjoyLCJuby11bnVzZWQtbGFiZWxzIjoyLCJuby11bnVzZWQtdmFycyI6Miwibm8tdXNlbGVzcy1jYXRjaCI6Miwibm8tdXNlbGVzcy1lc2NhcGUiOjIsIm5vLXdpdGgiOjIsInJlcXVpcmUteWllbGQiOjIsInVzZS1pc25hbiI6MiwidmFsaWQtdHlwZW9mIjoyLCJuby11c2UtYmVmb3JlLWRlZmluZSI6Mn0sImVudiI6e319fQ==)

Comment: You are just hoisting their declaration, which JS already does for you, that's why the code works in the first place. While your answer is correct and I agree that disabling linting rules is rarely not the way to go, I think in this case the best option is to disable that specific rule on that specific line using `tslint:disable-next-line:no-use-before-define` rather than obfuscating the code to trick the linter.

Comment: @Danziger yes, I agree on that, upvoted your answer. Just wanted to provide an alternative solution